# Using Powerline for telephone and internet

Tags: networking, ethernet, powerline-networking, telecommunication

As far as I know, CAT 5 cable can be used to run a 100 Mbps Ethernet and a telephone connection (2 pairs each). Would it be possible to use power line with this cable?

Comment: Do you mean can you put power over twisted pair?

Comment: no what I want is use a device such as  devolo dLAN 1200+ to use my powerline as a network cable and since you can use CAT 5 for telephone and network i thought maybe this device would be able to pass throught both so i dont have to bother with drilling holes in the wall for the telephone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass POTS (Plain Old Telephone System, AKA analogue phone system) down a TCP/IP network so you won't be able to use analogue phones with a PowerLine system.

Indeed, PowerLine systems only take a single master Ethernet feed from your router so you would need two separate systems if you had even a digital PBX.

Instead, the way to do it is to use VoIP. For that, you will need a system that takes POTS as an input and converts it to VoIP and visa versa. Then your data and voice can both occupy the same Ethernet cable.